# Cannot create property 'validator' on string 'input1'

Tags: angular, reactive

So instead of having a nested formGroup in the same component, I want to have a child component that I can integrate in a parent component. 
Should the the controls from the child be added to the FormBuilder of the parent? And how? I do want to have the entire model in the FormBuilder group definition, including the child fields.

I added the controls from the child in the FormBuilder (just as below, AS IF they had been defined in the parent) and I get an error:

Cannot create property 'validator' on string 'input1'

The four involved files are below:

parent.ts

```
this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
       'input1': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
        'myNestedGroup': this.formBuilder.group({
        'input2': [{ value: '', disabled: false }]      ///? correct
      })
    }
  );
```

parent.html

```
<child-selector>
</child-selector>
```

child.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, AbstractControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-selector',
  templateUrl: './child-selector.html'
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  myInput = 'input2';
  formGroup = 'myNestedGroup';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

child.html

```
<div [formGroup]="formGroup" >
    <input type="text" [formControl] = "myInput" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the formBuilder the input1, myNestedgroup and input2 aren`t correct the don`t need ''

```
this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
           input1: [null, [Validators.required,  Validators.minLength(3)]],
            myNestedGroup: this.formBuilder.group({
            input2: [{ value: '', disabled: false }]      ///? correct
          })
        }
      );
```

Comment: Thanks Tiago taken into account, but I still get the same problem

Comment: Can you provide a stackbliz?

Comment: found the problem will post the solutiuon later in case anyone else comes across the same

Comment: @annepic What's the solution?  I'm hitting the same issue